# compileOnSave stop working

Tags: angular, highcharts, typeorm

I build ng4 project with "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6" and the compileOnSave worked o.k when I added :

"@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",

```
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
"angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
"sqlite3": "^3.1.13",
"typeorm": "0.0.11"
```

the compileOnSave stop working ,

what can be the reason ?
how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm was having a similar problem today and am not using @ngx-translate/core so that didn't explain the issue for me.

It turned out that my app was having a runtime issue on load, and making further edits within the ng 4 app didn't compile on save. After I fixed the run time issue compileOnSave resumed functioning as normal. Not sure if that helps..i.e. ensure there are no run-time errors interfering with normal behavior of compileOnSave.